# Autocomplete anywhere per word for JComboBox/JTextField

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I found different solutions to add autocomplete on JComboBox but all of them work by autocomplete from the beginning. I'm looking for a solution similar to [JQueryUI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (if you enter *av* in the textfield, it popup *Java* and *JavaScript*).

For example, if I have the following items :

- "Red"
- "Blue"
- "Green"

If I enter *n*, I would like to have a match with *Green* since it contains a *n*.

Here are the solution I previously tested which match only from the beginning:

- AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox) from [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/)
- AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboBox,
  GlazedLists.eventListOf(elements)); from [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/)
- jautocomp from [jautocomp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jautocomp/)
- Java2sAutoComboBox.java

All the solutions above are matching from the beginning (all use startWith method), which is not what I'm looking for.

Do you know other solutions similar to the JQueryUI implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mentioned methods by supplying substrings to them instead of the full string:

```
1. check against the full string
2. check against the substring starting at position 1
...
n. check against the substring starting at position `n-1`
```

limited by the length of the full string

So for your example you would do the followings:

> 1. Does "Green" match "n" in the beginning? No -> next position
> 2. Does "reen" match "n" in the beginning? No -> next position
> 3. Does "een" match "n" in the beginning? No -> next position
> 4. Does "en" match "n" in the beginning? No -> next position
> 5. Does "n" match "n" in the beginning? Yes -> select the full word ("Green") as match

Comment: Could you provide an example, I'm not sure I see how to do it?

Comment: I think I understand the principle but how can I modify AutoCompleteDecorator, AutoCompleteSupport or other solution accordingly?

Comment: Hmm, reading through the documentations on the listed auto-complete libraries/classes makes me think those are overly restricting and does not allow any other way, but matching from the beginning.  Unless you find one that allows matching on custom substring, it appears you will have to create your own auto-complete popup logic